# Show that $q(z) \neq 0$ on the neighborhood $N(z_0,r)$ by continuity.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $g$ is analytic and never zero on $N(z_0,r)$, and that $g$ has a zero of order $m$ at $z_0$.

By the factorization theorem, we have $g(z) = (z-z_0)^m q(z)$ where $q(z_0)\neq 0$ and $q(z)$ is analytic on $N(z_0,r)$.

How do i show that $q(z) \neq 0$ on the neighborhood $N(z_0,r)$ by continuity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By mere continuity? You can’t. However, for all $z ∈ N(z_0,r)$, you have $g(z) = (z-z_0)^m q(z)$ as you say. So $q(z) = 0$ would imply $g(z) = 0$, which is impossible for $z ≠ z_0$. And on the other hand, you already have $q(z_0) ≠ 0$ by assumption.

(Remark: You can deduce that $q(z) ≠ 0$ on $N(r',z_0)$ for *some* real $r' > 0$ by mere continuity of $q$ using $q(z_0) ≠ 0$, but that $r'$ might be a lot smaller than $r$.)

Comment: @LittleRookie But, … I just showed this in my answer?

Comment: Can we have a stronger assumption that $g(z)$ is not zero on $z_0$ instead of a neighborhood of $z_0$, and show that $q(z) \neq 0$ on the neighborhood?

Comment: As in the answer: If $g(z_0) ≠ 0$, then there is *some* real $r' > 0$ such that $g(z) ≠ 0$ for all $z$ in $N(r',z_0)$ and then – by the same argument as before – $q(z) ≠ 0$ for all $z$ in $N(r',z_0)$. And that’s the best that you can get.

Comment: Proof of @k.stm's claim: consider $g(z) = (z-z_0)^m * (z - (z_0 + r'))$; that has a zero of the right order at $z_0$, but for $r' < r$ is NOT nonzero on $N(z_0, r)$.